# Converting Optional<> to List<>

Tags: java, list, spring-boot

I have a section of code that used to utilize Optional<Department>, but due to some errors I worked out I am now converting it to List<Department>. Obviously this means I now have to change the return types and other method calls. Here are my questions:

- I changed my returns to "new LinkedList<>()" (indicated in the code below) but is that correct?
- There is a red error under ".isPresent" (indicated in the code below) with error message "The method isPresent() is undefined for the type List<Department>". What should I be changing that to?

Below is the updated code with comments indicating where errors are now occurring. Any help and explanations would be GREATLY appreciated!

```
public List<Department> delete(String department_ID) {
    if ((department_ID == null) || (department_ID.isEmpty())) {
      return new LinkedList<>();      //<<<<<<<<<<<<<<< used to be "return Optional.empty();"
    }

    List<Department> existing = get(department_ID);
    if (existing.isPresent()) {    //<<<<<<<<<<< red error under ".isPresent()"
      String sql = "DELETE employee.*, department.* " + "FROM employee, department "
          + "WHERE employee.department_ID = :department_ID AND department.department_ID = :department_ID;";

      MapSqlParameterSource parameters = new MapSqlParameterSource();
      parameters.addValue("department_ID", department_ID);

      int rows = jdbcTemplate.update(sql, parameters);
      if (rows > 0) {
        return existing;
      }
    }
    return new LinkedList<>();     //<<<<<<<<<<<<<<< used to be "return Optional.empty();"
  }
```

- I changed my returns to "new LinkedList<>()" (indicated in the code below) but is that correct?
- I have googled the error message for my ".isPresent" error and cant find any explanations that fit

Answer (score 1):

## tl;dr

Change:

```
if (existing.isPresent()) { …
```

… to:

```
if ( ! list.isEmpty() ) { …
```

## Details

You said:

> red error under ".isPresent" (indicated in the code below) with error message "The method isPresent() is undefined for the type List".

The variable `existing` holds a reference to a `List` object. If you look at the Javadoc for [`List`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/List.html), you find no method named `isPresent`. So of course trying to call a non-existent method generates an error from the compiler.

That `isPresent` method was from the [`Optional`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Optional.html) class. The method checks to see if the optional holds a payload or if the optional is empty.

You seem to be switching to a style where you always expect a `List`, even if the list is empty (no elements).

If you want to be defensive, you can check that the list object exists.

```
if ( Objects.nonNull( existing ) ) { … }
```

But you can omit that null check if you are confident that such a condition cannot exist.

You may want to check if the list is empty, to avoid a needless call to your database. If so, change that code to:

```
if ( ! list.isEmpty() ) // Perform database work only if list has some elements.
```

---

You have other issues. Among them:

- Generally the convention in Java is to avoid underscores in names. And generally best to avoid ALL-CAPS.  So `departmentId`, not `department_ID`.
- When returning lists, generally best to return an [unmodifiable list](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/List.html#unmodifiable). If the calling programmer needs a modifiable list, they can easily make from the returned unmodifiable list.
- To get an unmodifiable list, use [`List.of`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/List.html#of()) rather than `new LinkedList<>()`.
- I cannot understand why your `delete` method would return a list. You may believe that you are reporting rows that got deleted, but technically you are not.

---

By the way, a tip: [Text blocks](https://openjdk.org/jeps/378) can help with embedded SQL.

Comment: Thank you for your feedback! I am a beginner student in a coding bootcamp, so I am not surprised you found additional issues. I will work on those as well!

Answer (score 0):

Instead of returning `new LinkedList<>()` you could return `List.emptyList()`.

`isPresent()` is a method of Optional, but you assign the outcome of method `get(department_ID)` to an instance of List. You can check the List using

```
if(!(existing == null || existing.isEmpty())) {
```